# Seperate faces from mesh without creating new parts?

Tags: modeling, mesh, workflow

This has bothered me for so long... I like to seperate some faces from my mesh but without creating a new mesh or part, I could press <kbd>P</kbd> and *Seperate by Selection* but then I have to switch to *Object Mode*, join them and swtich back to *Edit Mode*. Too many steps for my lazy butt... I could duplicate those faces, hide the duplicate, delete the original faces and keep the duplicate but it seems unconvinient.

Is there no magic button I'm unaware off?

Comment: I guess you misformulated it, you want to separate a part of the mesh, not separate objects, so Gorgious is right, use Y

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- With the object selected, hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> for *'Edit Mode'*.
- Press <kbd>3</kbd> for *'Face mode'*.
- Select the face/s you want to separate.
- Press <kbd>Y</kbd> to [Split](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/mesh/split.html) - or if you don't want to use the keyboard shortcut:
- Look for the *'Mesh'* tab at the top left.
- Click for drop-down list, find *'Split'*.
- Hover over *'Split'* for secondary drop-down list.
- Select *'Selection'*.

Done.